# Clearing All Cells in Current Table in Numbers

Tags: macos, iwork-09

Is there a quick way to clear all the cells in the current table in Numbers? I know all I have to do is press command-a, delete, and press down, but I would like to do it with one or two clicks if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution for this on Stack Overflow: [Getting the Current Table in Numbers (Python/Appscript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694060/getting-the-current-table-in-numbers-python-appscript). I attached the Service created by it to the hot key command-ctrl-c, which I can use now to clear the cells.